# how to display each article total comments

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I have two tables which I have joined. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT *, AVG(rate)
FROM comments c 
LEFT JOIN supps s     
on c.tutorialid = s.tutid 
WHERE category = 'Protein' 
GROUP BY tutorialid
ORDER BY $orderby $sort LIMIT $startrow,$limit";
```

And I have the code below to get the total comments:

```
//find the number of comments
    $commentNum = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

When I use `echo $commentNum`, it displays the total for all comments on every row for example if I had:

```
echo "".$row['title'] ."<br>";
echo $commentNum .
```

It would give me the total comments for all the posts rather the total for each individual post. Can anyone tell me what I have got wrong? How can I get total comment for each post?

Comment: Please click on the `?` button editor to learn how to format your code. Also, proper capitalization and putting question marks on questions is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I would try adding `COUNT(*)` in your initial `SELECT`. So your query would read

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*), AVG(rate)
FROM comments c 
LEFT JOIN supps s     
ON c.tutorialid = s.tutid 
WHERE category = 'Protein' 
GROUP BY tutorialid
ORDER BY $orderby $sort LIMIT $startrow,$limit";
```

Comment: thanks for your comment Tarek, I tried that but still get the same result.

Comment: Can you include sample data in the format you want/expect it? That might make things easier to visualize.

Comment: I want to have a list of my latest articles which the show titles, descriptions, rating and total comments, I want it to look something like the list of articles here: http://n4g.com/channel/xbox-360